# How to attach to WWAHOST from Visual Studio 11

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

If I F5 a Windows 8 JavaScript app and look at the processes pane in VS11, I see that it's WWAHOST.exe that I'm attached to. Is it possible to attach to this after the fact using Debug | Attach to Process? I don't see it in the process list even when I show processes from all users. I see the same thing whether I run locally or in the Simulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are effectively two ways to do this. Delay starting the app and attaching the app. You will need to install the remote debugger from Microsoft. As of this writing, it is located on http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28973

Detailed steps plus explanations are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Attach_the_debugger_to_a_running_app_).

Summary:

1. Install VS remote tools
2. On start menu, launch "Debuggable Package Manager" (powershell will start)
3. using powershell: get-appxpackage (to locate your package)
4. using powershell: enable-appxdebug PackageFullName
5. Launch application
6. Attach to the correct wwahost.exe for your application.

Debugging Topics Located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Bob. So it sounds like connecting to the simulator is identical to connecting to another machine (I suppose that makes sense since the simulator is simply a remote connection to my machine).

Comment: Absolutely. And yes, it's a very similar scenario in terms of what the simulator is doing.